# Store value at unspecified index in an Array. What's faster?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Say I want to add a value to an array, but it doesn't matter where, as long as the current item at that index is null. This null could be anywhere in the array, at random locations. I just want to have my value 
*somewhere* in my array. Should I iterate over it like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if (items[i] == null) {
            items[i] = obj;
            return;
        }
```

This way it may have to iterate over a lot of elements before it finds a null spot. Would it be faster to use another type, i.e. ArrayList ?

This is for a game, so performance is very crusial, and this is done maybe 300 times per second (also accessing, and deleting items).  So for a game, what should I use best to store items, to iterate over ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing but try a Queue or List

Comment: How do you retrieve items? Do you need random access to them (sounds like it) or do you just iterate over them. You might also consider a Map or Set, depending on how you access items.  Have you actually tested the performance of some of the standard Java Collections? There's no point agonising over what _might_ affect performance until you've measured it...

Comment: I just iterate over it, and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I have used in the past is to use an array and a Queue.  Any time you add a object to the array you first check your queue to see if you have any empty slots.  Anytime you destroy a object you set the array slot to null and add the index to the queue so you can quickly pull it out later.  During my tests this was faster than a List because you only resize the array if you make it bigger.

code wise

```
Queue<int> emptySlots;
Object[] arrayOfStuff;

public void AddStuff(object stuffToAdd)
{
    if (this.emptySlots.Count > 0)
    {
        int index = this.emptySlots.Dequeue();
        //make sure your objects know their position in the array
        stuffToAdd.ID = index;
        this.arrayOfStuff[index] = stuffToAdd;            
    }
    else
    {
        //resize array and add new object to end rememebering to fetch its id
    }
}

public void RemoveStuff(object stuffToRemove)
{
    this.emptySlots.Enqueue(stuffToRemove.ID);
    this.arrayOfStuff[stuffToRemove.ID] = null;
}
```

Comment: You may need to modify the code a bit, I thought this was a C# question and I'm pretty sure Queue is an interface in java but it should be something very similar

Comment: LinkedList is what I thought of, or is this bad for the performance?

Comment: If I am not wrong, even though you use queue, isn't lookup going to cost time?

Comment: LinkedList looks like it will provide the functionalty you need, I can't speak if its performance will be better or worse than any of the other queue types.  Best bet is to test its performance under the conditions your going to use it for and see if the speed is acceptable for your application

Comment: @thinksteep as far as I know about lists and queues, search operations and the automatic internal array resizing that happens when you add or remove items are some of your biggest costs.  Using the queue with a self managed array will prevent the array from downsizing when you destroy an object inside of it like lists tend to do.  Now most of my experience comes from c# but its likely the functionality is very similar

Comment: you can use a hash map, over a queue, and it will give better expected time

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor that piece of work in many different ways using the numerous [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/reference.html) implementations but do you need it ? Is that necessary ? Will that improve your performances ? Do you have realtime constraint (meet deadline) ? Are these few lines of code your bottleneck ? Your array has 64 boxes, can it be resized ? Are the items mostly null at the end of the array of at the beginning ? Do you need to be Thread-safe ? Did you run a stress / load test and measure how much time you spend in these lines (average, lowest and highest) ?

There are many optimizations you can do but they will depend on the behavior of your application.

Maybe you can rethink slightly your program to improve performances. IMO it usually is the most efficient. Did you think of replacing your array by something else ? You can do your own implementation (a lightweight one) of the [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface to manage the relevant (non-null) items. If you were relying on the position in the array, then you can add that information in the items (I suppose these are Objects).